# Can SSRS do excel like functions as expressions such as adding 1 cell from a column to another?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have searched and searched but can't find the answer. I am building an SSRS report that provides a running total. I need to be able to do the equivalent of I2+J3 and have the next row be I3+J4, etc. My report uses 1 dataset. Is this possible?

[Running Total Example Pulled From Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF8ft.png)

Comment: You could try using `ReportItems!TextBox1Name.Value + ReportItems!TextBox2Name.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. By using RunningValue function I can accomplish this task.

=RunningValue(!Fields.Charges.Value,sum,"DataSet1") creates the running total.

Answer (score 0):

you can use expressions in SSRS and also use grouping. looks like a duplicate of

[SSRS Expression-Sum two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543287/ssrs-expression-sum-two-fields)

see also

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74e73cd3-46ce-4812-ad15-3adc50438c04/sum-two-fields-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I looked at that, but it does not answer my question. I need to add a row to the next row of another column just like I3+J4. different rows,